# create($data) in zend framework 2 does not receive anything

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-rest

I was applying a tutorial about creating a restful application using ZF2 rest api.

I faced a weird problem, all of the rest action work perfectly except `create($data)`

```
public function create($data)
{
    $data['id'] = 0;
    $form = new AlbumForm();
    $album = new Album();
    $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
    $form->setData($data);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
      $album->exchangeArray($data);
      $id = $this->getAlbumTable()->saveAlbum($album);
      return $this->get($id);
    } else {
      return new JsonModel(array("data" => 0 );
    }
}
```

I used restful plugin in Firefox and the data look like that

```
artist=testName&title=testTitle
```

I traced the problem and figured that the variable `$data`always empty and does not store any value. On the other hand, when I use `update($id, $data)` every thing work fine

```
    public function update($id, $data)
    {
      $data['id'] = $id;
      $album = $this->getAlbumTable()->getAlbum($id);
      $form = new AlbumForm();
      $form->bind($album);
      $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
      $form->setData($data);

     if ($form->isValid()) {
       $id = $this->getAlbumTable()->saveAlbum($form->getData());
     }

    return new JsonModel(array('data' => $data));
   }
```

So could I have some suggestions?

**Update one :**

here is the `module.config.php` file to see if there is a mistake in it or not

```
<?php
return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'AlbumRest\Controller\AlbumRest' => 'AlbumRest\Controller\AlbumRestController',
    ),
), 
// The following section is new` and should be added to your file
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album-rest' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/album-rest[/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'id' => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'AlbumRest\Controller\AlbumRest',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
    'view_manager' => array( 
        'strategies' => array(
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ),
    ),
);
```

**Update two :**

the problem was from the Firefox RestfulClient. I installed the postman and it worked perfectly.

Comment: do you get any errors on create function?

Comment: @dixromos98 No, 
    Status Code: 200 OK
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Content-Length: 18
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Date: Mon, 29 Sep 2014 07:54:31 GMT
    Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100

but when I return or save the content $data it show it as empty.

if ($form->isValid()) evaluate as false, I really don't know what why $data doesn't receive anything it may be a problem with the routes I will update the post

Comment: can you also display the data you pass in the create function?

Comment: artist=testName&title=testTitle

Comment: okay so that is the problem. The reason it evaluates false is because the setData method expects an array. so you should convert the data from artist=testName&title=testTitle to data = array(artist=>testName, title=>testTitle)

Comment: Basically the $data should validate against your form fields. You can find more info here http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post, the problem was from the plugin I tested postman restful extension and it work.